# Colorgradient not displaying properly on StatsPlots corrplot

Tags: julia, histogram2d, julia-pkg

I am trying to obtain a `corrplot` of some three-dimensional data array using Julia. The StatsPlots documentation includes the following example of a `corrplot`:

```
M = randn(1000,4)
M[:,2] .+= 0.8sqrt.(abs.(M[:,1])) .- 0.5M[:,3] .+ 5
M[:,3] .-= 0.7M[:,1].^2 .+ 2
corrplot(M, label = ["x$i" for i=1:4])
```

[image: Corrplot example]

However, when I try to run the same script, I obtain flat histograms (no color gradient):

[image: local host example]

I generated the previous figure with the following script:

```
using StatsPlots
gr()
M = randn(1000,4)
M[:,2] .+= 0.8sqrt.(abs.(M[:,1])) .- 0.5M[:,3] .+ 5
M[:,3] .-= 0.7M[:,1].^2 .+ 2
corrplot(M, label = ["x$i" for i=1:4])
savefig("corrplot_example.png")
```

I am not sure what I am doing differently. My Julia version is 1.3.1, and my StatsPlots version is 0.14.6.